# Count how many times button is clicked Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

My ajax call on click redirects me to /undefined, /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php has value 0

I'm using Divi theme, custom ajax script which is localized:

```
function my_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'increment_counter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slug-ajax.min.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'increment_counter', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Counter function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_increment_counter', 'my_increment_counter');   
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_increment_counter', 'my_increment_counter');

function my_increment_counter(){
// Name of the option
$option_name = 'my_click_counter';
// Check if the option is set already
if ( get_option( $option_name ) !== false ) {
    $new_value = intval(get_option($option_name)) + 1; 
    // The option already exists, so update it.
    update_option( $option_name, $new_value );
} else {
    // The option hasn't been created yet, so add it with $autoload set to 'no'.
    $deprecated = null;
    $autoload = 'no';
    add_option( $option_name, 1 , $deprecated, $autoload );
}
}
```

Ajax file has this jQuery code for increment counter:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.activate-popup-animation').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'increment_counter',
        },
        type: 'POST',
    })
    .done(function(){
        // go to the link they clicked
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    })
    .fail(function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    })
});
});
```

Now, plan is to create custom widget in dashboard and call this function:

```
get_option('my_click_counter')
```

Where I'm making mistake, is that url problem with call action?

Answer (score 0):

---

Your ajax function should call some action, in this case "my_increment_counter", but instead you wrote "increment_counter", same with wordpress hooks. It should be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_increment_counter', 'my_increment_counter');   
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_increment_counter', 'my_increment_counter');
```

Comment: Changing hook from my_increment_counter to increment_counter doesn't make any changes. It keep redirecting to /undefined

Comment: It works now, I mean no more redirection, changed window.location = $(this).attr('href'); to console.log('clicked'); but it display static number and I have no idea where it gets that number

Comment: You should have either my_increment_counter or increment_counter in every case. In Ajax function action, name php function and add the same in filter. In php function, you must use `exit;` at the end of the function, to not get the static number.